# Load javascript in consecutive order after browser load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

**What am I trying to do?** In an attempt to speed up my website I am loading non-essential javascript after the browser load event. (So the JS files are not render blocking) This is currently functioning correctly.

**What is the problem?** The problem is sometimes the non-essential javascript depends on other libraries and plus those libraries need to load first.

**What have I tried to do to fix the problem?** In an attempt to fix the problem I have added a delay event to library dependent javascript. While this works sometimes, the load times of a JS file varies between refreshes and at times can load before the library even with a delay.

**QUESTION:** Does anyone know of a better way for me the load JS files only after the first JS file has loaded? (See code below)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
var element2 = document.createElement("script");
var delay=40;
element.src = "http://119.9.25.149/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/bootstrap_nova/js/highcharts.js";
element2.src = "http://119.9.25.149/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/bootstrap_nova/js/future-plastic.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);

    setTimeout(function(){
document.body.appendChild(element2);
},delay);


}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;

</script>
```

As you can see from the above, I am trying to load the highcharts js file before I load the future-plastic file.

Comment: Use a module loader like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not the first to have this problem, thankfully. There's a lot of difficult solutions around this problem, including using a module loader as suggested in the comment (which I agree is the best long term solution, because they account for more browsers and flexibility, but it's a lot to learn to solve one small problem).

The place to start learning about this problem and the ways to tackle it are all over the web. This is a pretty good resource: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/

You may want to try defer if you don't have to support Opera Mini or IE9. Or, you can load sync and execute as it loads- their examples is this:

```
[
    '//other-domain.com/1.js',
    '2.js'
].forEach(function(src) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.async = false;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

The reason why this **might** work (different browser implement this differently) is because the default is to load dynamically generated script tags are set to async by default, if you set it to false: "they’re executed outside of document parsing, so rendering isn’t blocked while they’re downloaded"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ScriptElement.onload`:

```
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function C(t){
  return doc.createElement(t);
}

function downloadJSAtOnload(){
  var s = C('script'), ns = C('script'), h = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var u = 'http://119.9.25.149/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/bootstrap_nova/js/';
  s.type = ns.type = 'text/javascript'; s.src = u+'highcharts.js'; h.appendChild(s);
  s.onload = function(){
    ns.src = u+'future-plastic.js'; h.appendChild(ns);
  }
}
downloadJSAtOnload();

}
```

Note: The first `onload` is `window.onload`, since `window` is implicit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mind explaining the above a little further? How does it work?